# HasDatepicker class added automatically

Tags: jquery

My datepicker is not shown when I click the textbox.
My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Picker</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#MyTextbox").datepicker();
        });  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Birth date <input type="text" name="MyTextbox" id="MyTextbox" /> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use F12 in the browser I see that a class "hasDatepicker" has been added automatically. Is this related? Why the datepicker is not shown?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? jQuery UI 1.8.20 is pretty old, have you tried the most recent version?

Comment: Verified your code with jQuery 2.2.1, jQuery UI 1.12.1. It's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure here, but I believe that there may be an issue with your linked script tags or the versions of jquery and jquery-ui used as the comments mentioned. I couldn't really verify your included script tags as I wasn't able to add [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery-ui) for the older versions, but your code seems to work fine when adding the jQuery 2.2.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1 as shown in the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#MyTextbox").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Picker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Birth date <input type="text" name="MyTextbox" id="MyTextbox" /> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#MyTextbox").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Picker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Birth date <input type="text" name="MyTextbox" id="MyTextbox" /> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```